# Convert query MySQL to Query DSL Elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I was the first person Elasticsearch new research

Help me convert this MySQL query to a DSL Elasticsearch query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM zone_articles 
WHERE data_status = 1 
  AND author = 123456 AND (namespace is NULL OR namespace = '456')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is strange condition "OR data_status = 1", we have already checking that's true early.
For ES (with correspoinding query editing) query is simple:

```
{
    "filtered":
    {
        "filter":
        {
            "bool":
            {
                "must":
                [
                    {"term": {"data_status" : 1}},
                    {"term": {"author" : 123456}},
                    {"term": {"namespace" : "456"}}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: result set would contains records ONLY with data_status = 1, that's why your "OR" condition is useless and redundantly

Comment: but what if I want to write OR queries?